# python MemoryError: storing big lists of different types

Tags: python-2.7, out-of-memory

I'm working with python2.7 and i need to build the followind data struct:
it must store all triplets  such that: x < y < z < N (N is given).
i can choose a triplet randomly.
i have a "Pop" function with input  that removes that triplet from the database if it exist or return "False" if it is not in the database.

N can be very large.

my code:

```
N = 1000
Root = []
for x in range(0,N-2):
    xNode = [x, []]
    for y in range(x+1,N-1):
        yNode = [y, []]
        for z in range(y+1,N):
            yNode[1].append(z)
        xNode[1].append(yNode)
    Root.append(xNode)
    print "Loading [{0:.2f}%]".format(float(100*x)/(N-2))
```

in my PC with `N=1000` there is a `MemoryError`. I want a datastruct instead of `[]` that stores parts into memory. i don't care if it is slower as long as it is not bounded by `N` (atleast for `N` smaller then the disc space in my PC)

is there a module or something else that can be used?

Comment: Please use *code blocks* (symbol `{}` in the editor) to include python code *not* stack snippets (symbol `<>` in the editor). Stack Snippets are **only** for HTML/CSS/JavaScript *runnable* examples, they don't work with other languages.

Comment: In any case, since you are using python2 you should use `xrange` instead of `range`. Also, depending on what you want to do with `Root` you could just store `xranges` in the innermost loop: `yNode = [y, xrange(y+1, N)]; xNode.append(yNode)`. This should use way less memory, and be much faster. The downside is that you cannot *modify* an `xrange`, but all other operations still work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your question, you want a workaround for that empty list and repeated appending.

When I run your program, in my local machine, the output for N = 4, was this:

```
>>> N = 4
>>> Root = []
>>> for x in range(0,N-2):
...     xNode = [x, []]
...     for y in range(x+1,N-1):
...         yNode = [y, []]
...         for z in range(y+1,N):
...             yNode[1].append(z)
...         xNode[1].append(yNode)
...     Root.append(xNode)
... 
>>> for i in Root:
...   print i
... 
[0, [[1, [2, 3]], [2, [3]]]]
[1, [[2, [3]]]]
```

I assume here that you at least want the output to seem like this:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

To achieve this, you need to make a small change in your code. Instead of that temporary `xNode` and `yNode`, you could append each list directly in the innermost loop.

```
>>> N = 4
>>> Root = []
>>> for x in xrange(0, N-2):
...   for y in xrange(x+1, N-1):
...     for z in xrange(y+1, N):
...       Root.append([x, y, z])
... 
>>>
```

Now, for N = 1000, the approximate length of the list will be `O(N^3)` or around `10^9` which is pretty big for a local machine. To give you an idea, each element of the list constitutes of 3 integers. Assuming a size of integer to be `4 bytes`, each element of the list will be of size `12 bytes`. Total memory required to store the complete list in memory will be `12*(10^9) bytes` which is approximately `11 GB`.

Regarding the main problem of checking and popping off elements, you can do it as follows:

The idea is to assume that all the valid triplets are initially present in memory (though we won't store it because you mentioned that `N` can be very large and we cannot store all triplets for larger values of `N`). We will make three `N` sized lists - `x`, `y` and `z`. Whenever we pop off a triplet, we will mark the corresponding values in these lists. At a later moment, if we encounter the same triplet, then we can check in `O(1)` time whether it has been popped off or not. The space complexity will be `O(N)` and the time complexity will be `O(queries)`.

```
N = int(raw_input())
# number of queries
queries = int(raw_input())
x = [0]*N
y = [0]*N
z = [0]*N
for i in xrange(queries):
    a, b, c = map(int, raw_input().split())
    if a < b and b < c and c < N:
        # Basic idea is if (x[a], x[b], x[c]) = (1, 1, 1), then it has already
        # popped off, else, we pop it and mark it as popped.
        if x[a] == 1 and x[b] == 1 and x[c] == 1:
            print 'Triplet not in memory to remove'
        else:
            x[a] = 1
            x[b] = 1
            x[c] = 1
            print 'Triplet (%d, %d, %d) popped off memory' % (a, b, c)
```